# Use find + sed + cp to find files and copy them to a directory with a different name

Tags: sed, find, cp

I'm trying to copy a bunch of files named folder.jpg into a folder. The problem is because all the files are named the same thing, I need to rename them in the process. I know I can probably do it with sed but I'd like to rename them to the name of part of the parent folder.
Here is what I got just to find and copy the files

```
cp $(find . -iname "folder.jpg") .albumart/
```

The folder structure is ./artist/artist.year.album/folder.jpg and what I'd like to use the parent folder (or just part of it) to name the file. Can someone help me with a one liner to accomplish the task?
To make things even trickier, some folders have one more level of CD1 and CD2 that I would like to ignore if they are present (e.g. ./artist/artist.year.album/CD1/folder.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have `bash`, this version simply takes your folder structure (e.g. `./foo/bar/baz/folder.jpg`) and replaces all the slashes with underscores (e.g. so you get `foo_bar_baz_folder.jpg`):

```
find . -iname folder.jpg -exec bash -c 'for x; do x=${x#./}; cp -i "$x" ".albumart/${x//\//_}"; done' _ {} +
```

Note that no matter what you do, any time you move files from multiple locations into the same destination, there is always a chance of a name collision.

Comment: I believe this will move the .jpg files rather then copy is that correct? I think I'd just need to replace it with 
`find . -iname folder.jpg -exec bash -c 'for x; do x=${x#./}; cp -i "$x" ".albumart/${x//\//_}"; done' _ {} +`
correct?

Comment: @Rothgar Yes, I didn't read carefully enough and assumed you wanted to move.  I've changed the `mv` to `cp` now.

Answer (score 3):

With zsh:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n -C '(**/)folder.jpg' '.albumart/${1:t}.jpg'
```

Remove `-n` when happy.

That one will avoid name collisions (will fail with an error if two substitutions resolve to the same name) like:

```
$ zmv -n -C '(**/)folder.jpg' '.albumart/${1:t}.jpg'
zmv: error(s) in substitution:
b/c/folder.jpg and a/b/c/folder.jpg both map to .albumart/c.jpg
```

Comment: +1 for `zmv`. By far the easiest and whitespace-safe-est option for this sort of thing.

Comment: I like the idea. Any way to take out the spaces in the names (replace them with _)?
I'm going to have to go find some more documentation on zsh and zmv for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse the output of `find`. This breaks if there are whitespace or glob characters `?*\[` in file names. If you use `find`, make it call the command with the `-exec` action. Call a shell in the `-exec` action to perform the necessary string transformations.

```
find -name folder.jpg -exec sh -c '
    dir=${0%/*}      # stip off the file name
    case $dir in */CD[0-9]) dir=${dir%/*};; esac
    cp -ip "$0" ".albumart/${dir##*/}.jpg"
' {} \;
```

---

Zsh's [zmv](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) is often the easiest way to do this kind of copying.

```
zmv -C -o-p -w '**/*.jpg' '.albumart/${${${1%/}/CD<->}##*/}.jpg'
```

Some explanations:

- The general syntax is `zmv OPTIONS… SOURCE_PATTERN REPLACEMENT`.
- `-w` turns on wildcard group matching. In the replacement text, `$1` refers to the part matched by `**/` (with a final `/` unless the matched text is empty, i.e. the file is in the top directory), and `$2` to the part matched by `*` in `*.jpg`.
- Both the pattern and the replacement text must be protected against expansion: they need to be passed literally to `zmv`.
- To understand `${${${1%/}/CD<->}##*/}`, take it from inside out. First take `$1`. Strip off a final `/` (if any). Strip off a final pattern matching `/CD<->`, if any ([`<->`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) matches one or more digits). Finally off everything but the last directory component.
- If you want to replace spaces by underscores, add one more layer of [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion):  `${${${${1%/}/CD<->}##*/}// /_}`.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously late with this answer, but hoping some others may find it useful.

```
for i in $(find . -type f -iname "folder.jpg" -printf "%P\n") ; do t=$(echo $i | sed 's|/|\.|g'); cp $i TARGETDIR/$t ; done
```

The `-printf "%P\n"` is to strip the leading `./` from `find`'s output.

Echo `find` result (`$i`) into `sed` and make alterations, in this case sed replaces `/` with `.`, and assign the value of that whole thing to `t`

Then just copy the file found by `find`, `$i` in this case, to the TARGETDIR with new name `$t`.

Found: `./artist/artist.year.album/folder.jpg`
Yield: `TARGETDIR/artist.artist.year.album.folder.jpg`