# Simple way to find files, apply changes, and write to another directory under different names?

Tags: shell, find

I wrote some script `foo` that accepts a file path, reads the file, applies some changes to it, and outputs the changed file to stdout:

```
foo src/file.foo > dest/file.changed.foo # works fine
cat src/file.foo | foo > dest/file.changed.foo # also works fine
```

Now, I want to apply this command to multiple files in a directory and for every file do:

> src/file.foo --> foo --> dest/file.changed.foo

Based on the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63683/41546) to a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63680) I've come up with the following:

```
find src -name '*.foo' \
  -exec bash -c 'for x; do dest=${x/src/dest}; foo ${x} > ${dest/\.foo$/.changed.foo}; done' _ {} +
```

The above works, but the problem is that it's too complicated for everyday use. **Isn't there a simpler way to do it?** I was wondering if it's the way `foo` is done that complicates things.

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot less typing and fiddling if you use recursive globbing. In bash, put [`shopt -s globstar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) in your `.bashrc`. In ksh93, recursive globbing requires `set -o globstar`; in zsh it works out of the box. Beware that in bash, recursive globbing also recurses under symbolic links to directories.

To save on string manipulation, first change to the top of the source tree (or to the top of the destination tree).

```
cd foo
for x in **/*.foo; do foo "$x" >"../dest/${x%.*}.changed.foo"; done
```

You can omit the double quotes if you know that your file names don't contain whitespace or globbing characters.

In zsh, the double quotes are never necessary, and you can save some more typing even without changing the current directory.

```
for x in src/**/*.foo; do foo $x >../dest/${${x#*/}%.*}.changed.foo; done
for x in src/**/*.foo; do foo $x >../dest/${x#*/}:r.changed.foo; done
for x (src/**/*.foo) foo $x >../dest/${x#*/}:r.changed.foo
```

If you do this often, you should define a build rule, e.g. in a GNUmakefile (use a tab where I used 8 spaces):

```
source_files = $(shell find src -name '*.foo')
destination_files = $(patsubst src/,dest/,$($(source_files)%.foo=.changed.foo))

default: all-foo
all-foo: $(destination_files)

dest/%.changed.foo: src/%.foo
        foo $< >$@
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your filenames don't have embedded newlines:

```
find src -name '*.foo' -type f | \
    while IFS= read -r sf; do
        df=dest/${sf##./src/} && \
        mkdir -p "$(dirname "$df")" && \
        foo "$sf" >"${df%%.foo}.changed.foo"
    done
```

Comment: FWIW, you only need a single `#` and `%` in those expansions because there's no wildcards and so you're removing the "smallest" part; eg `${sf#./src/}`

Comment: @StephenHarris FWIW, if `./src/` and `.foo` are fixed, `##` and `%%` have the exact same effect as `#` and `%`. :)

Comment: Yes, they do the same thing but are unnecessary extra typing ;-)

Comment: I see you added a `mkdir ... && foo`; it shouldn't have a `&&` afterwards because `src/d1/a.foo` and `src/d1/b.foo` would both try to `mkdir dest/d1` and the second will break.  Instead `mkdir -p ... 2>/dev/null ; foo`

Comment: @StephenHarris Nope, `mkdir -p` doesn't return an error if the directory exists.  Proof: `mkdir -p foo; mkdir -p foo; echo $?`

Comment: Interesting; must be a change with `-p`; in the long long distant past it did error out :-)

Comment: Is it really simpler than the original solution? I mean, if I ask my colleagues (front-end devs) to enter that in the terminal, they will throw chairs at me and spill coffee onto my keyboard on purpose.

Comment: @StephenHarris IIRC it's intentional, and it has always been like that.   Anyway, I don't recall it ever being any other way, and I've been using UNIX before the time of dinosaurs. :)

Comment: @Oleg Not sure what "simple" means.  Short?  First thing that comes to mind?  Quick to run?  The above is the first thing that comes to mind for me (then again, I probably have a deeply perverted mind).

Comment: Easier to write and remember for casual shell users, I guess.

Comment: @Oleg Then I suppose the easiest for casual users would be to have a wrapper script that takes `src` and `dest` as arguments, and applies `foo` to all `.foo` files.  Otherwise it isn't a problem that has a simple __and__ safe solution, I think (not substantially simpler than the above, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have a tree of source files (eg no `src/dir1/a.foo`; they're all directly in the `src` directory) then you don't need the `find` wrapper and just do it directly in shell:

```
for x in src/*.foo
do
  dest="${x/src/dest}"
  foo "$x" > "${dest/%.foo/.changed.foo}"
done
```

The complication, here, is that you want to change filenames, and isn't a consequence of `foo`.

We can make it slightly easier if `foo` doesn't require to be run in the current directory

```
cd src
for x in *.foo
do
  foo "$x" > "../dest/${x/%.foo/.changed.foo}"
done
```

If you didn't want the extension changed then it's about the simplest loop possible

```
cd src
for x in *.foo
do
  foo "$x" > "../dest/$x"
done
```

All of these loops can be changed into a single line by strategic use of the `;` character.  eg the first loop becomes

```
for x in src/*.foo; do dest="${x/src/dest}" ; foo "$x" > "${dest/%.foo/.changed.foo}" ; done
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the source directory has `.foo` files in subdirectories.

Comment: Right; I was assuming no subdirectories because then we also need to ensure that the `dest` subdirectories have also been created; can't just do just `>dest/$name` when `$name` may have directory components.

Comment: I do have nested src directory structure, forgot to mention it in the question, but it's probably not a concern. I was just wondering: is `for` loop available on all *nix flavors or there're some gotchas? (sorry for being a noob... I should really read more about all this stuff)

Comment: The `for` loop is standard `sh`.  The `${../../..}` syntax is a `bash` and `ksh`; dunno if it's POSIX or not.